# Is it possible to hook up a Light/Fan combo switch with this wiring setup?

Tags: electrical

I would like to add a dimmer switch to my kitchen light but it is a ceiling fan. I understand that you should not use a regular dimmer switch with a ceiling fan, but would I be able to connect a Light/Fan combo switch with the existing wiring setup? [image]

Comment: It depends, where does the extra wire that’s capped off go?  They do make the single gang wiring device that you’re looking for, [here is one example](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B001JPXK2U/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_i_5Ac-AbDNP00ZS), there are many others tho.

Comment: Is running a new cable from the fan to the switch an option?

Comment: We have three fans in our house. The other 2 all have separate switches for light and fan. I was thinking that the extra wires in the box might have been to wire them up separately at one point. Also, is it ok to have the 2 ground wires pigtailed together? And no its not an option to run new wire.

Comment: It'd be a real nice to see a photo of what's going on in the box which supports the fan.  That capped off extra set almost makes a person think they left you extra wires for that purpose.

Comment: Going away for the week for work. Will post a picture of the wiring in the ceiling fan next weekend. Thanks